# Hyper-V Ubuntu Connects to Network but not Internet

Tags: internet, hyper-v

I am running Hyper-V on Win 8.1. I had no problems creating VMs running Windows 8.1 and Win Server.
I created one running Ubuntu, reused the same Bridged Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet adapter. VM running windows has no problem connecting to the Internet.
VM running Ubuntu can see my local network, and I can ping it from the network.
The problem is that Ubuntu VM cannot get on the internet.
So, the question is why VM running Windows connects to the INternet while VM running Ubuntu does not although adapters are the same?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of guest machine is getting assigned an ip address from DHCP server whilst its not the case for the second. Have you tried adding a **Legacy Network adapter** from Add Hardware Pane in Settings of Hyper V manager.

Try using a legacy network adapter to connect to your created external virtual switch.

If that doesn't work perhaps setting up static ip addresses to your virtual machines  might fix the problem.